# SASS: Atualização do arquivo css em pastas diferentes?

Tags: sass

Estou aprendendo SASS e gostaria de saber como atualizar um arquivo .css pelo sass, quando o arquivo *.scss* e o .*css* estão em pastas diferente. Por exemplo:

O *style.scss* está na pasta **scss** e o *style.css* está na pasta **css**.

Entendi que o comando `style.scss:style.css` gera o arquivo na mesma pasta, qual seria o comando para ele gerar em pastas diferentes?

Grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sass --watch input: output
```

ou seja:

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

Se estiver a utilizar apenas SASS, uma sugestão seria especificar o caminho de output ao compilar:

```
sass file.scss ../path/to/file.css
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui Flávio, não estava achando essa informação, ficou claro agora.

Grato!